# Regex in Javascript not as greedy as it should?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have made a simple code for capturing a certain group in a string :

```
/[a-z]+([0-9]+)[a-z]+/gi    (n chars , m digts , k chars).
```

[code](http://jsbin.com/irehej/2/edit) :

```
var myString='aaa111bbb222ccc333ddd';
var myRegexp=/[a-z]+([0-9]+)[a-z]+/gi;

var match=myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match)
 
 while (match != null)
{
  match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
  console.log(match)
}
```

The result were :

```
["aaa111bbb", "111"]
["ccc333ddd", "333"]
null
```

But wait a minute ,
Why he didnt try the `bbb222ccc` part ?

I mean ,
It saw the `aaa111bbb` but then he should have try the `bbb222ccc`... ( That's  greedy !)

What am I missing ?

## Also

looking at

```
   while (match != null)
    {
      match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
      console.log(match)
    }
```

how did it progressed to the second result ?
at first there was :

var match=myRegexp.exec(myString);

later ( in a while loop)

```
match=myRegexp.exec(myString);
match=myRegexp.exec(myString);
```

it is the **same** line ... where does it remember that the *first* result was already shown ?

Comment: Because the index after first match is at the end of the first match the bbb was already passed and nothing is left to match except the rest of the string which is `"ccc333ddd"`. Greedy means that `+` will attempt to match as much as possible without taking into account that the next part of the regex could match it.

Comment: hi @Esailija yeah  , I already understood that. but if it is greedy as it  say it is , it is not.

Comment: @Esailija please paste your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Esailija can you please have a look at my edit please?

Comment: @RoyiNamir It is greedy - but it won't go back and re-check an part of an expression that it has already matched

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.exec` is stateful when you use the `g` flag. The state is kept in the regex object's `.lastIndex` property.

```
var myString = 'aaa111bbb222ccc333ddd';
var myRegexp = /[a-z]+([0-9]+)[a-z]+/gi;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(myRegexp.lastIndex); //9, so the next `.exec` will only look after index 9
while (match != null) {
    match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
    console.log(myRegexp.lastIndex);
}
```

The state can be resetted by setting `.lastIndex` to `0` or by `execing` a different string. `re.exec("")` for instance will reset the state because the state was kept for `'aaa111bbb222ccc333ddd'`.

The same applies to `.test` method as well, so never use `g` flag with a regex that is used for `.test` if you prefer no surprises. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Comment: does it mean that if I wasnt keeping the regex in a variable , and always have used raw `/[a-z]+([0-9]+)[a-z]+/` , it wouldn't have remembered the index ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir yeah, when you create a new regexp object, it doesn't have any state yet. In other words, `/[a-z]+([0-9]+)[a-z]+/gi.lastIndex === 0` alwys

Comment: I didn't understand the `test` part. why shouldn't I use test with [g] ? becuase it yields >1 results ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir because it's the `g` flag that makes `.exec` and `.test` work statefully. If you remove the `g` flag, you notice that the lastIndex is 0 after a match with `.exec`

Answer (score 2):

You can also update manually the `lastIndex` property :

```
var myString='aaa111bbb222ccc333ddd';
var myRegexp=/[a-z]+([0-9]+)[a-z]+/gi;

var match=myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match);

 while (match != null)
{
  myRegexp.lastIndex -= match[0].length - 1; // Set the cursor to the position just after the beginning of the previous match
  match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
  console.log(match)
}
```

See this link [MDN exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

---

**EDIT :**

By the way your regex should be : `/[a-z]{3}([0-9]{3})[a-z]{3}/gi`